# How to invoke a kotlin function when given the function name as a string?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm making a project with many functions, each named prx, x being a number up to 200, is it possible to create a call from a string like this

`var ="pr" + x`

Comment: Why don't you create a single function taking that number as input instead?

Comment: This is almost certainly an XY problem where you are asking for a solution to something that isn't really a good way to solve your problem. If you could add some context to your question as to what you are trying to achieve that would be more useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using reflection

```
class MyTestClass {
    fun pr1(): Int = 5
    fun pr2(value: Int) = value.toString()
}


class SomeOtherClass{
    fun main(){

        val myTestClassObj = MyTestClass()
        // Find pr1 by name (function without arguments)
        val pr1 = myTestClassObj::class.java.getMethod("pr1").kotlinFunction

        // call pr1, pass class object as argument, used to call the function
        val pr1Result = pr1?.call(myTestClassObj)

        // Find function with arguments, pass function name and type of arguments
        val pr2 = MyTestClass::class.java.getMethod("pr2", Int::class.java).kotlinFunction

        // Call pr2, pass class reference and the function parameter
        val pr2Result = pr2?.call(myTestClassObj, 100)

    }
}
```

*Be carefull when working with reflection, its easy to create untraceable bugs using it and often it is only a workaround for bad design.*

Comment: Might make more sense to provide 2 functions, and call the getMethod from outside the class definition with "somefun" being variable and resolving to the name of those 2 functions. Confused me a fair bit what the relation was to the question.

Comment: question is `Given I have a string,which represents a function name. How do I call that function`.

Comment: @somethingsomething updated the code to be more clear and aligned with problem, thanks for suggestion

Comment: i'm still relatively new to kotlin, so sory if I'm missing something, but wouldnt this require me to create a val prx = bla bla bla for each function? or would just changing the "pr1" for a string variable work?

Comment: you can use a var prefix = "pr";  then do a loop and for each value of x, do `val functionName = prefix + x` now find the function using above approach